# ViewPager in a row of a RecyclerView - IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I tried to create a ***RecyclerView*** with multiple view type, including a ***ViewPager*** inside a row.

For this ***RecyclerView***, I integrate two libraries :

- The first one, [SuperSLiM library](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM), is used for the ***RecyclerView***, that integrates ***sticky header***.
- The second one, [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator), is used for the ***ViewPager***, that integrate indicators for it.

Well, the context is in place !

So, when I try to display my ***RecyclerView***, my application crash with the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0062 (com.tspckr.vpinsidercrow:id/rowViewPager) for fragment PageFragment{41fc0f78 #0 id=0x7f0c0062 android:switcher:2131492962:0}
```

But if I add a ***Handler*** with a delay for displaying data (like if I perform a network request), my ***RecyclerView*** is displaying but not the data in the ***ViewPager*** except the ***ViewPagerIndicator*** that show the indicators as waited.

Most interesting thing, if you try to scroll this ***ViewPager*** at his end and then rotate your device, the ***ViewPager*** will show (normally) his content.

I think this bugs was because the ***ViewPager*** is already instantiate and, when I try to attach the data, this doesn't update it or there is no more reference on it ...

Anyway, I don't know how to fix it.

> I don't want display any lines of code here, because, there is too much.
>
> Instead, I created a [GitHub](https://github.com/tspecker/sample-recyclerview-multipletype) which contain an easier copy of the project, directly runnable
>   (this copy retake exactly the same operations that the original).
>
> **Note** : The *Constant* **WITH_DELAY** allow you to run the application with a delay (simulate a network request) or not (instant crash).

Comment: Do check this https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/ if it helps

Comment: That's an interesting sample of code for customize a RecyclerView but unfortunately it doesn't help me.

Comment: Facing the same issue.

Comment: is this issue fixed? Whats the solution